# How to implement watch-only database using watchkit

Tags: sql, swift, watchkit, watchos

I am making a watch-only watchOS app. I am collecting answers to a few questions and I want to store it in a database on the watch itself.

I know that watchkit supports SQLite, but I couldn't find tutorials on how to set up an SQLite server on apple watch locally to store data.

It would be helpful if I could get links to documentation or example code for setting up and storing data locally on the watch app.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [realm](https://realm.io) for my standalone watch apps. It works pretty good and it takes care of all the db level things. You can even use cocoapods to add the sdk to your project. The only downside I found right now it is the longer install time of the app when debugging on the device.